# Parse through dictionary with list items

Tags: ansible, jinja2

My dictionary looks like this:

```
seed_job_additional_git_scms:
  TestUrl:
    credentials: "TestCredentials"
    branch: "testBranch"
    directory: "testDirectory"
  TestUrl2:
    credentials: "TestCredentials2"
    branch: "testBranch2"
    directory: "testDirectory2"
```

Now iterating normally using the ansible `debug` module, I get exactly what I want:

```
- name: Print 
  debug:
    msg: "Repo {{ item.key }} has credentials  {{ item.value.credentials }}. Its used branch {{ item.value.branch }} and gets saved to directory {{ item.value.branch }}"
  loop: "{{ lookup('dict', seed_job_additional_git_scms) }}"



TASK [copy : Print ] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'key': u'TestUrl', 'value': {u'directory': u'testDirectory', u'credentials': u'TestCredentials', u'branch': u'testBranch'}}) => {
    "msg": "Repo TestUrl has credentials  TestCredentials. Its used branch testBranch and gets saved to directory testBranch"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'key': u'TestUrl2', 'value': {u'directory': u'testDirectory2', u'credentials': u'TestCredentials2', u'branch': u'testBranch2'}}) => {
    "msg": "Repo TestUrl2 has credentials  TestCredentials2. Its used branch testBranch2 and gets saved to directory testBranch2"
```

Now I am trying to do the same thing buy in a template file using Jinja.

What Ive tried is this :

```
{% for dict_item in seed_job_additional_git_scms %}
   {% for key, value in dict_item.items() %}
      <h1>URL: {{key}}</h1>
      <h2>Credentials: {{ value.credentials }}</h2>
      <h2>Branch: {{ value.branch }}</h2>
      <h2>Direcotry: {{ value.directory }}</h2>
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

But Im getting the error :

```
TASK [copy : Template required files.] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
failed: [localhost] (item={u'dest': u'/tmp/config.xml', u'src': u'job.j2'}) => {"changed": false, "item": {"dest": "/tmp/config.xml", "src": "job.j2"}, "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'ansible.parsing.yaml.objects.AnsibleUnicode object' has no attribute 'items'"}
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `seed_job_additional_git_scms` is a dictionary.  When you write a loop like this...

```
{% for dict_item in seed_job_additional_git_scms %}
```

...then you are iterating over the **keys** of the dictionary. That means for each loop iteration, `dict_item` is a **string**.  That's why you're getting this error:

```
AnsibleUnicode object' has no attribute 'items'
```

Because a string object has no `items` method.  Additionally, you're using a nested loop to try and solve things which isn't necessary: even if we were to fix the issue with the outer loop, it still wouldn't do what you want. I think you want this:

```
{% for key, value in seed_job_additional_git_scms.items() %}
      <h1>URL: {{key}}</h1>
      <h2>Credentials: {{ value.credentials }}</h2>
      <h2>Branch: {{ value.branch }}</h2>
      <h2>Direcotry: {{ value.directory }}</h2>
{% endfor %}
```

Which results in:

```
      <h1>URL: TestUrl</h1>
      <h2>Credentials: TestCredentials</h2>
      <h2>Branch: testBranch</h2>
      <h2>Direcotry: testDirectory</h2>
      <h1>URL: TestUrl2</h1>
      <h2>Credentials: TestCredentials2</h2>
      <h2>Branch: testBranch2</h2>
      <h2>Direcotry: testDirectory2</h2>
```

Comment: Yep. TLDR: If you get such error, look for a place where you passed a string instead of dictionary.